# htmlWebpackPlugin doesn't add base tag

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to create an output html using the htmlwebpack plugin. Below is my configuration. The header is added to the HTML, but the base tag is not. The documentation says that the plugin has a base parameter that takes a string value. I did it by analogy with the example from the documentation, but the tag did not appear in the output file. What am I doing wrong? I found a workaround with the addition of a template, where i set up base tag,

```
template: 'src/index.html',
```

but I would like to solve the problem without it.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.(jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    'url-loader?limit=10000',
                    'img-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'App',
            base: '/',
            filename: 'index.html',
            isProduction: true,
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                keepClosingSlash: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true
            }
        })]
};
```

Comment: I was looking for the same and I fount that "this feature is only included in the current beta version html-webpack-plugin 4.x" https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1250

Comment: I forgot, I also found the [base-href-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-href-webpack-plugin). As of today it's working fine.